# How do you prove a graph **is not** planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Is there a theorem using the number of edges and vertices, or something about the max degree a vertex can have? I know that you can use $e ≤ 3v−6$. But what if that condition holds, and it still might not be planar? I'm having a hard time finding a planar representation for the graph I'm looking at.

Comment: There is a characterization due to Kuratowski, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem

Comment: There are many ways to show a graph is non-planar. We have that every non-planar graph has a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. We also have that if the minimum degree is greater than 5, the graph is non-planar. You can also look at induced subgraphs and try to find one where $e>3v-6$. If you provide more information about the graph you are looking at that would help.

Comment: There are a good number of Related Questions linked to the right on your post.  Have a look at (say) three of them to see if you can make your Question more precise.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that the graph I was looking at had a homeomorphic K3,3.

Answer (score 4):

As stated above, a variation of Kuratowski's and Wagner's Theorems are popular
for proving non-planarity of a graph. Another method could be to simply
refer to Euler's Formula for planar graphs i.e.
$$v - e + f = 2,$$
Where $v$ is the number of vertices, $e$ is the number of edges, and $f$
is the number of faces. Any connected planar graph has this equality holding,
and often we can prove a graph is non-planar by assuming it is planar, and
showing that it contradicts the above formula. Another variation of this
formula for planar graphs with multiple connected components is
$$v - e + f = k + 1,$$
where $k$ is the number of connected components within the graph.

Comment: I think you mean $v-e+f=\color{Red}1$ (unless you're counting the outside as a "face").

Comment: It is unclear how one can count faces without having a planar embedding to refer to.